What is the point of specifying second dimension when allocating 2D array in java
Suppose I have a following code:
int[][] arr = new int[1][1];
arr[0] = new int[2];

This is perfectly fine in Java - why? I assumed it allocates memory for a single-element array that can hold single element-array.
If I can pass an array of arbitrary size to arr[0] why am I even able to specify the second dimension size?
Is there any use case when
int[][] arr = new int[1][1]; 

is actually useful over
int[][] arr = new int[1][];


I can come up with a case when you want to create the array immediately instead of looping through the first dimention. Also useful when you read the size from some input, you just specify new int[size][size] (only in case you need a square).

Suppose, for matrix mathematics,  you have public class Matrix { private int [][] matrix;  public Matrix (int numRows, int numColumns) {  ###  }.  Is there any reason you would not prefer to replace ### with matrix = new int [numRows][numColumns]; ?  You could have matrix = new int [numRows]; for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) { matrix[i] = new int [numColumns]; }. But, is that preferable?

If you don't specify the second dimension, the first dimension will consist of an array of nulls. If you do, it will consist of an array of arrays of the 2nd dimension.

Sometimes (perhaps most of the time) we want to define a 2D array all of whose subdimensions are the same size.  For example, to define a 2×2 array we can use:
int[][] arr = new int[2][2];

But occasionally we might have the need to define a jagged array, for example:
int[][] arr = new int[2][];  // 2D array with 2 rows
arr[0] = new int[3];         // first row has 3 columns
arr[1] = new int[1];         // second row has just 1 column

Jagged arrays can be useful in cased where we don't want to use the same subarray size in all cases.
